# Regrouping data based on an indicator value

Tags: r, transform

I have a dataframe with two columns as shown below,

```
   Name                Indicator
   DeAngelo Williams   1
   Marcus Brown        1
   Elaine Nelson       2
   Steve Olson         3
   Jennifer Carter     1
   Michael Johnson     2
   Angela Brawley      3
   Dax   Shepard       4
```

What I am trying to do is combine all the names where the Indicator Column values is 1 until the next value 1 is encountered, the final output should looks like this below.

```
          Name 
          -------               
          DeAngelo Williams   
          Marcus Brown,Elaine Nelson,Steve Olson
          Jennifer Carter, Michael Johnson, Angela Brawley, Dax Shepard
```

I am unable to think of a solution for this issue so any assistance on accomplishing this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R` to do this.  As @thelatemail mentioned in the comments, create a group by doing the cumulative sum of the logical vector `Indicator==1`, using the formula method, we `paste` the elements in 'Name' together.

```
aggregate(Name~cbind(Group=cumsum(Indicator==1)), df1, FUN=toString)[2]
```